# Odd internal space between text and line on Toggable Tabs - Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, css-float

I'm experiencing a problem that is quite hard to put into words. I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rguhxgoe/) to try and express what is the problem.

There, you will notice this: the texts `[Home, Profile, Messages, Settings]` and 
their `bottom-border` grey are really far from each other.

[image]

I noticed that if I go to this part of the code (Line 31) and remove the `float: left`, the problem will be solved, but then the layout will behave differently than what I expect (2 sections aligned).

```
.user-left{
    width: 196px;
    float: left; /* This is at line 31 on Fiddle */
}
```

Can anyone point me to the direction on why is this happening?

Comment: Add `.nav-tabs { overflow: hidden;}`

Comment: Thank you. No idea why that worked...